# WPF: How do I use ComboBox TextSearch?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Am I correct in assuming that Textsearch in a ComboBox gives me a text input box at the top of the ComboBox that filters out when I type in?

If so I do not understand why it's not working. I have a ComboBox with its ItemsSource bound to a ListCollectionView through the DataContext. I set IsTextSearchEnabled to true and set TextSearch.TextPath to a property of the object type in the ListCollectionView:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PersonCollection}"
          TextSearch.TextPath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"/>
```

However I never get any inputbox.

The property definitely works as that is displayed as I did set in DisplayMemberPath.

Am I assuming wrong and if so how does text search work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to set IsEditable true.

Comment: I had seen alot of examples but never noticed IsEditable being set. It works, thank you.