# WPF : Close combobox on item selection and display Message box

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

**Goal**  I have Combobox in WPF and whenever a user selects the item from Combobox I want to close the Combobox (displaying old value as selected value) and display MessageBox with Ok/Cancel button. If a user clicks Ok, the new selected value should be set else it should return.

**Problem** When I'm selecting item I'm able to display the MessageBox along with Combobox open, which I dont want. As soon as user selects something I want to close the Combobox and display Messagebox.

How I can do it?

**XMAL** code

```
 <ComboBox Name="Currency" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" ItemsSource="{Binding comboboxSource}"
                        SelectedValuePath="Value.bank_currency" IsReadOnly="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Value.bank_currency" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBankCurrency, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,Mode=Twoway}">
```

**C#** Code

```
public KeyValuePair<string, bankCurrencyObject>? SelectedBankCurrency
    {
        get { return _selectedCurrency; }
        set
        {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to change the currency?",
                       "Warning",
                       MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
                       MessageBoxImage.Question);

                if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    //set values
                }
   }
   }
```

**Attempt using selectionChanged event** but this did not work,

```
  private void Combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext == null)
            return;
        var combo = (sender as ComboBox);

        if (combo != null && combo.IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            combo.IsDropDownOpen = false;
            var binding = combo.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty);

            binding.UpdateSource();
            binding.UpdateTarget();
        }
    }`
```

Comment: `if (result != MessageBoxResult.Cancel) _selectedCurrency = value;`

Comment: @Vyrira I had tried this but with this also Combobox does not close and overlap with MessageBox

Comment: Don't you have access to the Currency combobox? You could set `Currency.IsDropDownOpen = false;` before showing the MessageBox.

Comment: Use `SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: I noticed you haven't set `IsEditable` to `True`, are you using the [TextSearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088744/wpf-combobox-textsearch-how-does-it-work)? If not there's a simple solution to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Vyrira All my properties are in ViewModel but I can access combobox in code behind

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Yes I tried SelectionChanged event but event that did now work, added my approach in my question. I'm I missing anything?

Comment: @Funk Yes, I'm using TextSearch on Combobox.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on the `SelectionChanged` event.

The `selectedItem` field keeps track of the previously selected item so that it will not show a `MessageBox` when there is no change of currency. If the selected item has been changed it hides the DropDown menu before showing the `MessageBox`. Then if the user clicked Cancel it reverts the change otherwise it stores the current selection in `selectedItem` to compare in the future.

```
private object selectedItem = null;

private void Currency_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Currency.SelectedItem == selectedItem)
        return;

    Currency.IsDropDownOpen = false;

    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to change the currency?",
           "Warning",
           MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
           MessageBoxImage.Question);

    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
        Currency.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
    else
        selectedItem = Currency.SelectedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can span a Task on the .Net thread pool and display a message box through a dispatcher.